# Find Clusters of Responses in Survey

Tags: clustering, python, sas

I have results from a survey:

```
ID    Ques    Answer
1      a        yes
1      b        yes
1      c        no
2      a        no
2      b        yes
2      c        no
3      a        no
3      b        no
3      c        no
```

I would like to see if there are any relationships/clusters between answering yes to the questions. I have data for around 2000 participants, with around 30 questions each. I'm wondering if I should construct a distance matrix, by converting the yes/no to 0/1, follow [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21421/clustering-survey-responses-based-on-dichotomous-responses) previous question. Any idea if I could reproduce similar methods in SAS or Python?

***EDIT: I think I'm trying to cluster questions, as opposed to people. I would like to see if a group of questions are often answered "yes" together, or the opposite, that answering "yes" to `a`, is predictive of answering no to `b`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing sounds more like **frequent itemset mining** to me. Because not all questions will cluster.

Questions are your items, each questionnaire is a transaction. You'll need fairly high thresholds, since each user answers each question.